# Page moves on link submit

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I was wondering if anyone knew how, when on link submit the page does not move i.e

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

If it was 2 page lengths down it would shoot up to the top.

Comment: What do you mean by "link submit"? Are you doing the "link submission" via JavaScript?

Comment: when clicking on the link i want a small box to open undernieth it

Answer (score 3):

If you have attached event to HTML control through jQuery then you can use `return false` like

```
$("#myDiv").delegate("tr", "click", function() {    
     enter code here
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to replace anchors, as your own answer to the question states.

This will work just as well:

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourOwnSubmitFunction(); return false;">
```

In short, just make sure that whatever function is in the onClick handler returns boolean `false`.

Comment: onclick="return yourOwnSubmitFunction();" is better. It should return false, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst having the link's `onclick` handler `return false;` is the correct way to stop a link being followed, it's a bit of a hack to use a link this way, because what you've got is an action and not a link. You can't do the usual link-like things to your link, like right-click-bookmark, or middle-click-for-new-tab and so on, so it shouldn't really have that affordance.

An alternative (that eg. SO uses) is to put the onclick on a non-link element instead, eg.:

```
<span id="potato">Do something</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('potato').onclick= function() {
        // do something
    };
</script>
```

This is cleaner, but has a drawback in is that the link can't be focused and activated by the usual keyboard tabbing method.

Arguably better is to use an `<input type="button">` or `<button type="button">`, which are the right markup to represent an action. Of course these look quite different, but you can use CSS to style them so that they look like a link instead of a button if you like. The one drawback of this method is that good old silly IE cannot completely restyle a button; you will get a few pixels of unremovable extra padding in this browser.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I might start using this method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net 2.0

There is a

**[MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx)**

property in @page directive that you can use to maintain the scroll position of the page.

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether to return the user to the same
>   position in the client browser after
>   postback. This property replaces the
>   obsolete SmartNavigation property.
>
> When Web pages are posted back to the
>   server, the user is returned to the
>   top of the page. On long Web pages,
>   this means that the user has to scroll
>   the page back to the last position on
>   the page.
>
> When the
>   MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback()()()
>   property is set to true, the user is
>   instead returned to the last position
>   on the page.

If you can't use this then set location.href to an anchor tag at the specified position after the submit.

```
location.href = "#anchAtPos";
```

where anchAtPos is the id of the anchor tag at a specified position.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using:

```
function anchorReplace()
{
    $("#reportWrapper a").each(function(i){
        var anchorElement = $(this);
        var newAnchorElement = $('<a href="#link' + i + '" name="#link' + i + '">' 
            + anchorElement.text() + '</a>').insertBefore(anchorElement);
        anchorElement.remove();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this before by putting

```
onclick='return false;'
```

Inside the link

```
<a href="#" onclick='return false;' id='attachAlistenertothisID'>This link doesn't jump to the top!</a>
```

I use this for my links that have click listeners attached them via jQuery.

Hope this helps someone!